# Erro em detalhes da ordem em magento

Tags: php, html, css, xml, magento

Olá. Estou com um erro no magento que não consegui resolver de forma alguma. A página de detalhes da ordem está sendo exibida desta maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei diversas soluções, como substituir o core do magento, alterar permissões e diversas outras soluções, todavia, nada funcionou.

O log de erros:

```
2017-02-17T13:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 107: parser error : Double hyphen within comment: <!--<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="pr  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                 <!--action method="setLogoType"><value>wePrefer_150x60</value></  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                   ^  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 108: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: layout line 30 and block  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():             </block>  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                     ^  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 109: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():         </reference>  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:54:17+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():         ^  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:56:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 107: parser error : Double hyphen within comment: <!--<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="pr  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:56:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                 <!--action method="setLogoType"><value>wePrefer_150x60</value></  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:56:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                   ^  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:56:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 108: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: layout line 30 and block  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:56:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():             </block>  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:56:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                     ^  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:56:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 109: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:56:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():         </reference>  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2017-02-17T13:56:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():         ^  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
```

Como devo proceder para solucionar este problema?